# How to convert Haskell System.Directory getHomeDirectory to a regular String?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm a Haskell noob and, at the moment, only use it to configure xmonad.

I want to put my config into a git repo, for that I want to not have to hardcode my home dir to grab my icons.

I checked out 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_get_rid_of_IO
but I am just too ignorant to understand it.

```
hd h = h =<< getHomeDirectory

getIcon::String -> String
getIcon out = ( "^i("++hd++".xmonad/dzen2/"++out )
```

Is this actually possible? If so, how?
I don't want to operate on the directory, I just want the path, as a String and it's killing me.

Error is:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
>             with actual type `(FilePath -> IO b0) -> IO b0'
> In the first argument of `(++)', namely `hd'
> In the second argument of `(++)', namely
>   `hd ++ ".xmonad/dzen2/" ++ out'
> In the expression: ("^i(" ++ hd ++ ".xmonad/dzen2/" ++ out)
> ```

Looks to me like the IO monad was not removed at all.

Update:
Alright. I'll learn how to adapt to IOs rules, until then I'll keep things hardcoded and clone the config file with a script that will replace the appropriate bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `getIcon` has the wrong type, since `getHomeDirectory` does IO:

```
getIcon :: String -> IO String
getIcon out = do
     hd <- getHomeDirectory
     return $ "^i(" ++ hd ++ ".xmonad/dzen2/" ++ out
```

Remember that Haskell distinguishes code that has side effects -- such as reading your hard disk -- via the type `IO`.

So the caller would be in IO too:

```
main = do
    s <- getIcon "foo"
    .. now you have a regular string 's' ...
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the IO bit, it is what's giving me trouble. I need the returned IO String as a regular string, since that's what the configuration expects. Your code did help me understand something else, though. do and return with $

Comment: @Erius There is no (safe) Haskell function of type `IO String -> String`.  What happens in `IO` stays in `IO`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the code at the point where you're calling `getIcon`?

If you can get the home directory before calling it, you could do

```
getIcon :: String -> String -> String
getIcon out hd = ( "^i("++hd++".xmonad/dzen2/"++out )
```

and then wherever you're calling from (assuming it is in `IO` as well)

```
someIOFunction = do
    things
    ....
    hd <- getHomeDirectory
    getIcon out hd
```

Just to point out a last resort if nothing else works, there is [`unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3aunsafePerformIO), but I've never actually had to use it (and I feel like it is generally frowned upon), so I can't help you too much there.

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` is a special tool for very special purposes and you don't need it (you'd know if you needed it).

Comment: Well *I* don't need it... just giving options.  My answer is already silly in light of dons' edit.  Major whoosh moment on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You can "break out" of other monads, but you can't break out of the IO monad. Something like this in your Xmonad configuration file is probably what you want:

```
getIcon::String -> String
getIcon out = ( "^i("++hd++".xmonad/dzen2/"++out )

main =
   h <- getHomeDirectory
   let myIcon = getIcon "Firefox"
   xmonad $ desktopConfig . . . -- use myIcon somewhere in this expression
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to unwrap certain `IO` values at compile-time, using Template Haskell. One's home directory is a reasonable candidate, since it doesn't change particularly often. A Template Haskell solution for getting the home dir as a string at compile-time might be coded like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module HomeDirectory where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import System.Directory

myHome :: String
myHome = $(LitE . StringL `fmap` runIO getHomeDirectory)
```

Be warned that Template Haskell is a notoriously tricky beast, though. This example is simple enough, but it can easily end up complex and confusing.